# How to create png image from SVG with Custom Fotns

Tags: php, wordpress, imagick

I converted SVG to PNG by using Imagick library. I have used custom fonts in SVG file but it doesn't load custom forts in PNG . How can i use custom fonts while conversion from SVG to PNG???